# Selenium: How to wait for a string inside InnerHtml (SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers)

Tags: .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I want to create a method in my selenium test, which does wait until an element with a specific string inside the InnerHTML is displayed.

Currently I have this here:

```
string textToCompare = "Hello";
w.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath(PathElement))).GetAttribute("innerHTML");
```

In the codeline above, im just waiting for `PathElement` and get the attribute of the `innerHTML`.

But i want this to behave like: *Wait for the element which has the `textToCompare` string inside of its innerHTML*

If there are other waiting methods for selenium, i would be open for any suggestions.

Or is there a way to navigate with the `PathElement` variable directly to the InnerHTML?

Here is the inspect of the webpage:
[image]

Comment: try fluent wait

Comment: How is _`PathElement`_ defined?

Comment: PathElement is just a simple XPath. In this case `string PathElement = "//p[@class='mud-typography mud-typography-body1 mud-surface-text mb-4']"`. Our website is using mudblazor, which creates elements dynamically. So thats why the naming of the element is weird and has not a specific ID.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the `inspect`. The red circles is the text i want to wait for using the waitmethod. I know that i can easily wait just for the `PathElement`, but i want to wait for a specific string inside innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

To wait until an element with a specific string as the *`InnerHTML`* is displayed instead of `ElementExists()` you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*ElementIsVisible()*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementIsVisible.htm) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `ElementIsVisible()` and *Text* attribute:

  ```
  string PathElement = "//p[@class='mud-typography mud-typography-body1 mud-surface-text mb-4']"
  w.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(PathElement))).Text;
  ```
- Using `ElementIsVisible()` and starts-with specific text:

  ```
  string PathElement = "//p[@class='mud-typography mud-typography-body1 mud-surface-text mb-4' and starts-with(., 'Importiere')]"   
  w.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(PathElement))).Text;
  ```
- Using `ElementIsVisible()` and containing specific text:

  ```
  string PathElement = "//p[@class='mud-typography mud-typography-body1 mud-surface-text mb-4' and contains(., 'Importiere')]"  
  w.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(PathElement))).Text;
  ```
- Using `ElementIsVisible()` and generic text:

  ```
  string PathElement = "//p[@class='mud-typography mud-typography-body1 mud-surface-text mb-4' and text()]" 
  w.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(PathElement))).Text;
  ```